# serving favicon.ico from node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have built a small node server using express and I want to serve index.html which contains angular app. How ever the browser sends GET request for favicon.ico. I have installed serve-favicon, however still it looks for physical file. Is there a way to override it? or from where can I find such file

Comment: Unfortunately, the favicon needs to be a `.ico` file. You can generate the `.ico` file from normal png/jpeg files (using a website like [this one](http://www.favicon-generator.org/)). Then to implement, use: `app.use(require('serve-favicon')(__dirname + '/path/to/favicon.ico'));`

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way is actually just to use a link tag in your index.html:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.png">
```

Just change the href to link to an img in your public folder and you're good to go.

http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [site](https://www.freefavicon.com/freefavicons/objects/) to get free favicon.ico

Then add your favorite favicon.ico to your html .

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../images/favicon.ico" />
```